# Teradata: count number of weekends between two timestamps

Tags: sql, timestamp, teradata, weekend

I would like to count the number of weekends between two timestamps. My data sits in Teradata. I can't use a raw time difference because starting points will vary.

Comment: You aren't giving us much to work on. Sample data would certainly help.  But take a look at the built in calendar view - `sys_calendar.calendar`.   It's got a day of the week column that you can use to identify your weekends.

Answer (score 0):

The week difference should be equal to the count of weekends between two Timestamos, so just try:

```
ABS(td_week_of_calendar(TS_2) - td_week_of_calendar(TS_1))
```